# Merging two dataframes with an added condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I got two dataframes that I need to merge as per follows:

Df1

```
Name Type Speed  
a x  1  
a y  0  
a z  1
```

Df2

```
Type Fast Slow  
x 2 3  
y 3 5  
z 4 6
```

Df3 - DESIRED OUTCOME

```
Name Type Speed Time  
a x 1 2  
a y 0 5  
a z 1 4
```

So basically I need to create a new `'Time'` column that displays times from either `'Fast'` or `'Slow'` column based on `'Speed'` column and the object `'Type'`. I have literally no idea how to do this so any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance. Apologies for the confusing explanation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `merge` + `np.where` for a more succinct solution:

```
v = df1.merge(df2, on=['Type'])
v['Time'] = np.where(v['Speed'], v.pop('Fast'), v.pop('Slow'))

  Name Type  Speed  Time
0    a    x      1     2
1    a    y      0     5
2    a    z      1     4
```

Comment: Yes this worked with dropping the speed off the original merge as that column did not exist in df2. Thank you so much! 
v = df1.merge(df2, on=['Type'])
v['Time'] = np.where(v['Speed'], v.pop('Fast'), v.pop('Slow'))

Answer (score 1):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for reshape first, then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for correct match `Speed` and last [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
df = df2.melt('Type', var_name='Speed', value_name='Time')
df['Speed'] = df['Speed'].map({'Fast':1, 'Slow':0})
print (df)
  Type  Speed  Time
0    x      1     2
1    y      1     3
2    z      1     4
3    x      0     3
4    y      0     5
5    z      0     6

df3 = df1.merge(df, how='left', on=['Type','Speed'])
print (df3)
  Name Type  Speed  Time
0    a    x      1     2
1    a    y      0     5
2    a    z      1     4
```

If performance is important `merge` is not necessary - [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) - `df1['Speed']` is `0` and `1`, so is processes like `False`s and `True`s:

```
s1 = df2.set_index('Type')['Fast']
s2 = df2.set_index('Type')['Slow']

df1['Time'] = np.where(df1['Speed'], df1['Type'].map(s1), df1['Type'].map(s2))
print (df1)
  Name Type  Speed  Time
0    a    x      1     2
1    a    y      0     5
2    a    z      1     4
```